# how to use values from coroutines outside of coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

How do I use the response from a room database outside of the coroutine it was called from

I need to use coroutines to execute a request from a room database, then take this data display it in a recyclerview. The problem I'm having is that I can't get the response from the database to show up outside of the coroutine.

my code.

```
class seconddisplay : AppCompatActivity(){
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.second_display)

    GlobalScope.launch {
        val respo = second_Database.getInstance(context = this@seconddisplay).DAO().seeAllcodes()

    }

    second_recyclerview.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@seconddisplay)
        adapter = displayAdapter(respo)
    }
}
```

I also can't put the recyclerview code within the coroutine because it says you can't touch the hierarchy of the view.

Comment: No you can't, you should put that code inside the launch block. There's no way you can pause the code (except blocking it) until respo call bas been finished. It is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Activity` or `Fragment` you can use `lifecycleScope` to launch a coroutine, by default it runs on the `Main` coroutine context, therefore you can update your UI from there:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    // call like this if `seeAllcodes()` method is suspend
    val respo = second_Database.getInstance(context = this@seconddisplay).DAO().seeAllcodes() 

    // call like this if `seeAllcodes()` method isn't suspend
    val respo = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // runs on background thread
        second_Database.getInstance(context = this@seconddisplay).DAO().seeAllcodes()
    }

    // update UI
    second_recyclerview.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@seconddisplay)
        if (respo != null) {
            adapter = displayAdapter(respo)
        }
    }
}
```

To use `lifecycleScope` add next line to dependencies of the app's **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.0-alpha05"
```

Comment: thank you very much. this has helped immensely. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could use the respo variable as a global variable of the class.And then use the property withContext(Dispatcher.main) to use the mainthread and wait for the result.Something like this:

```
private var respo: YourDataType? = null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.second_display)
   getRespo()
   
}

private fun getRespo(){
   val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()
   val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + supervisorJob)
   coroutineScope.launch {
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
      respo = second_Database.getInstance(this@seconddisplay).DAO().seeAllcodes()
      second_recyclerview.apply {
      layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@seconddisplay)
        if(respo!=null){
          adapter = displayAdapter(respo)
        }else{//handle respo being null, maybe show a message 
          }
        }
     
      }
   }
   
}
```

Comment: So if the asyncronous code didnt finished then is null and nothing happens?

Comment: the thing is that the asyncronous code is being executed in the main thread so it is blocked until it is finished. But it is a good idea to put handle that with an else block. just edited the answer

Comment: For that the apply should go inside the with context

Comment: You are right! I didnt noticed I put it outside of it! I edited now so it is inside! thank you very much!